# How to save multiple Winforms Chart images to disk correctly?

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, charts, io

I'm in a situation where I have say 10 instances of a ChartData class. I cycle through them and create a Chart (Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart) for each instance.

```
//pseudo-code
foreach (var data in chartData)
{
  chart = new Chart();
  PopulateSeries(chart);
  chart.SaveImage(path, format);
}
```

Inside the loop, after populating the chart series with the data, I try to save the image using chart.SaveImage(path, format). However, I am noticing that when I step through the debugger, all 10 images are being created, but without any breakpoints, only the first and last images are created--8 images are missing!

I understand this might be due to I/O issues, but how can I make this process asynchronous? The Chart class does not seem to allow saving the image asynchronously.

Comment: Can you post real code instead of pseudo-code? Debugging pseudo-code is pseudo-debugging. Do you change `path` at some point, for example? You don't need an asynchronous `SaveImage()`. You possibly need a asynchronous `PopulateSeries()`.

Comment: _I understand this might be due to I/O issues_ Unlikely. Do you create proper path names? you could add a File.Exists after the save to make sure it worked..

Comment: I like the File.Exists idea, will give that a shot. I'll post real code in a bit. Path does not change, only the image name changes. Again, I want to emphasize that the *exact same code* has different behavior when under debugger and without.

Comment: Please consider posting [MCVE].